# Finding whether there exists a pair of numbers in a set having a given product

Tags: python, algorithm, complexity

> Devise an algorithm that will operate on a number x and a set of n
> distinct numbers such that in \$O(n \lg n)\$ time, the algorithm indicates
> whether or not there are two numbers in the set that have a product of
> x. Explain why your algorithm works.

My algorithm:

1. Sort the set //\$ O(n \lg n)\$
2. For every element in the set check if x % element =0 // \$O(n)\$
3. If so check if the dividend x/element exists in the set // \$O(\lg n)\$
4. If dividend exists and is not equal to element, the two numbers in the set (element and dividend) have a product of x.

This algorithm works because it only returns true when the condition(x=element*dividend where element and dividend are in the set) to be satisfied is met. And upon quick Analysis we can see that the algorithm is running at \$O(n\lg n)\$ for the sort and \$O(n)*(\lg n)\$ for checking if the two elements exists. Therefore it is running at \$O(n \lg n) + O(n \lg n) = O(2n \lg n) = O(n \lg n)\$

Can I have some feedback on my solution — whether you think it is correct or not and where you think it can be improved?

```
def findIfProdExists(x,items):
    items = mergeSort(items) # O(nlgn)
    for item in items:
        if(item!=0):
            if x%item ==0:
                if(find(x/item,items)and item!=x/item):  #binary Search O(lgn)
                    return True
    return False

def mergeSort(aList):
    size = len(aList)
    first = aList[:int(size/2)]
    second = aList[int(size/2):]

    if(size ==1):
         return aList
    if(size ==2):
        if(aList[1]<aList[0]):
            return list([aList[1],aList[0]])
        else:
            return aList
    else:
        return merge(mergeSort(first),mergeSort(second))
        
            
def merge(list1,list2):
        newList =[]
        i1 =0
        i2 =0
        while(i1<len(list1) and i2 <len(list2)):
            if(list1[i1] <list2[i2]):
                newList.append(list1[i1])
                i1+=1
            elif(list1[i1]>list2[i2]):
                newList.append(list2[i2])
                i2+=1
        newList.extend(list1[i1:] +list2[i2:])
        return newList

def find(x,items):
    size = len(items)
    mid = int(size/2)
    if(size == 1):
        if(x == items[0]):
            return True
        return False
    elif(x==items[mid]):
       return True
    elif x> items[mid]:
        return find(x,items[mid:])
    else:
        return find(x,items[:mid])
```

Comment: Your program doesn't work for me: I get `NameError: name 'mergeSort' is not defined`.

Comment: Sorry about that I was just demonstrating the algorithm. I'll include the mergeSort Code so you may test.

Comment: Optionally you could use python's built in sort method on the list since from the python wiki https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity it also has a time complexity of O(nlgn)

Comment: Thanks for that. But it still doesn't work for me. Now I get `NameError: name 'find' is not defined`.

Comment: Sorry, another function I wrote to do a binary search. I just included it.

Comment: I tried `findIfProdExists(6, [2,2,3])` but I didn't get a result — the program seems to go into an infinite loop.

Comment: The question said the set should have unique numbers

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 13 → 12. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The algorithm description is good, but the implementation of `find` is \$ O(n) \$, so the overall runtime is actually \$ O(n^2) \$.

Detailed review follows:

1. There are no docstrings. What does each function do? How do I call it? What does it return? Are there any constraints on the parameters, for example do the inputs have to be sorted? or do they have to be free of duplicates?
2. It's not necessary in Python to have parentheses around the condition of `if` statement, and it's best to omit them.
3. According to the analysis, `find` needs to be \$ O(\log n) \$, but the actual implementation is \$ O(n) \$. Here's a demonstration:

   ```
   >>> from timeit import timeit
   >>> for p in range(2, 8):
   ...     items = list(range(10**p))
   ...     '{:f}'.format(timeit(lambda:find(0, items), number=1))
   ...
   0.000012
   0.000022
   0.000077
   0.001386
   0.038858
   0.417670
   ```

   The reason for this is the copying in the recursive calls. In Python, the list slice `items[mid:]` has to be copied, and the time taken to do this is proportional to the number of items in the copy. See the [time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) page on the Python wiki.
4. In order to avoid copying in `find`, it's best to keep indexes into the part of the sequence which might contain the item we're looking for:

   ```
   def find(x, items):
       """Return True if x is an element of the sequence items, assuming
       items is sorted.

       """
       lo = 0
       hi = len(items)
       while lo < hi:
           mid = (lo + hi) // 2
           if x == items[mid]: return True
           elif x < items[mid]: hi = mid
           else: lo = mid + 1
       return False
   ```
5. Python has a built-in module [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) for binary search of sorted sequences, and using this module it's possible to write `find` like this:

   ```
   from bisect import bisect_left

   def find(x, items):
       """Return True if x is an element of the sequence items, assuming
       items is sorted.

       """
       i = bisect_left(items, x)
       return i < len(items) and items[i] == x
   ```
6. The corrected version of `find` locates an element in a sorted list in time \$ O(\log n) \$. But it's possible to do better than that using a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set). Set lookup has average complexity \$ O(1) \$.
7. The implementation of `merge` goes into an infinite loop if `list1` and `list2` have a common item. This was easy for me to spot because there is an `if` … `elif` with no `else` at the end. When code has a sequence of conditions like this, it's always worth asking, "what happens if none of the conditions apply?"
8. Python has a built-in function [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) for merging sorted iterables into a single sorted iterator, and a built-in function [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) for sorting an iterable (using a variant of mergesort, as it happens). These are fast and well-tested implementations, and (except as an exercise) they should be used in preference to writing your own.
9. In `findIfProdExists` the division `x/item` is computed twice in some cases.
   It would be better to compute it once and remember the value.
10. In `findIfProdExists` the cheap test `item!=x/item` is computed after the expensive test `find(x/item,items)`. It's usually best to compute cheap cases first so that if they fail the expensive test can be avoided altogether.

Putting all this together, I'd implement the algorithm like this:

```
def product_pair(x, items):
    """Return True if there is a pair of distinct elements in the iterable
    items whose product is x. Return False otherwise.

    """
    items = set(items)
    for item in items:
        if item != 0 and x % item == 0:
            y = x / item
            if y != item and y in items:
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: Quick question though set lookup has a time complexity of  \$ O(1) \$ on average and  \$ O(n) \$ in the worst case according to the Python wiki. Doesn't that mean that in the worst case the algorithm would have a quadratic running time ?

Comment: Yes, it's theoretically possible that many elements have the same hash, but in practice this is not worth worrying about unless the elements come from an untrusted source.

Comment: Ok I see, but after making the suggested fixes to merge and find functions, is your implementation still optimal compared to sorting then doing a binary search ?

Comment: Why not do a performance comparison and see for yourself?

Comment: think i can answer my own question. on average it would be because yours would have a Time complexity of  \$ O(n) \$ right ?

Comment: On moderate-sized examples \$ \log n \$ is small, so the difference between \$ O(n \log n) \$ and \$ O(n) \$ depends more on constant factors than on asymptotic considerations. There's no substitute for measuring and making sure.

Answer (score 1):

Requiring the remainder of division of the target number by one from the set to be zero seems to imply the set to contain whole numbers, only:
the task never says so.
But if that's true, one never needs to handle numbers with an absolute value greater than the absolute value of the target.

There is one gripe I have with a rephrase of [Gareth Rees' answer](/a/84721/93149)

```
def product_pair(x, items, integral=False):
    """ Return True if there is a pair of distinct elements 
        in the iterable items whose product is x. Return False otherwise.
    """
    if x == 0:
        return any(items) and not all(items)
    if integral:
        maxfactor = abs(x)
        minfactor = -maxfactor
        items = { y for y in items if minfactor <= y <= maxfactor
                                      and y and x % y == 0 }
    else:
        items = set(items)
        items.remove(0)
    for item in items:
        y = x / item
        if y != item and y in items:
            return True
    return False
```

: when returning false, every element of items will have been checked as, say, the first factor: twice the number of checks as when exploiting commutativity.

One might populate four separate sets with limits -|target|, -√|target|, 0, √|target|, |target|.
Possible speed-up when sticking to binary search is not in substituting one comparison & recurse with one comparison & selection from one of four partitions, but from selecting small ones for iterating over:
For a positive target, pick the smaller positive one and the smaller negative one.
For a negative target, pick the smaller from each pair the opposite side of square root and zero.

```
import math

def product_pair(x, items):
    """ Return True if there is a pair of distinct elements 
        in the iterable items whose product is x. Return False otherwise.
    """
    if x == 0:
        return any(items) and not all(items)
    big_, small_, small, big = set(), set(), set(), set()
    root = math.sqrt(abs(x))
    _root = -root
    for item in items:
        if item < 0:
            (big_ if item < _root else small_).add(item)
        elif 0 < item:
            (small if item < root else big).add(item)
      # else:  # 0: see special case near entry
      #     pass
    combinations = ((big_, small), (small_, big)) if x < 0 \
              else ((big_, small_), (small, big))  # giving the right sign
    for factors in combinations:
        iterate, check = factors if len(factors[0]) <= len(factors[1]) \
                    else reversed(factors)
        for item in iterate:
            if x / item in check:
                return True
    return False
```